# Android "send to" function name

Tags: android, intentfilter

in my adroid application i have defined

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="application/epub+zip" />
  </intent-filter>
```

now i can send the data from other applications to mine.

But how can i modify the thext under the icon where the user selects the app to share his current content? I saw apps which changed it so something like "add to APPNAME". At the moment just my app name is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`android:label`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) attribute in the `intent-filter` element.